# Removing text of specific color from PDF

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file with some pink text (I can obtain the exact HEX code if necessary) that I need to remove. Can this be done automatically? It's got ~140 pages, so doing this by hand isn't an option.

My current idea is to:

1. Convert PDF to separate images, 1.png, 2.png etc.
2. Replace all occurrences of pink with a right shade of white (the
   result will be satisfying to me), ImageMagick should do the trick
3. Convert PNG files back into one PDF

It seems overly complicated though, and I won't be able to select/copy text anymore.

Can you recommend a better approach to this?

//edit: Screenshot of the pink text, as requested in a comment.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the pink area?

Comment: @Ravexina, I've edited the question to add said screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you can utilize inkscape somehow? Import the PDF -> create a script that removes all the pink text -> export it to PDF again. This should preserve the text copy/select stuff.

Comment: @Jibbow, seems viable, but I don't have any experience with Inkscape. Can you point me to resources (or help personally) as to how write an appropriate script?